# DRF: TypeError: <Model: Model object> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have problem getting an object data from the request using django-rest-framework ModelViewset `create(self, request)` method.

Here is my `model.py`

```
class Heat(models.Model):

    # Relationship Fields
    animal = models.ForeignKey(
                   Animal, related_name='heats', 
                   on_delete=models.CASCADE
             )

    # Fields
    performer = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    is_bred = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
```

And this is my `serializers.py`

```
class HeatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Heat
        fields = [
            'id',
            'animal',
            'performer',
            'is_bred',
            'note',
        ]
```

And here is where we can find the error in my ModelViewset:

```
class HeatViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Heat.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HeatSerializer

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            print serializer.validated_data['animal']
```

If you look at this line of code:

```
// this purpose is to print the actual value of an animal object 
// but it gave me the TypeError: <Animal: Animal object> is not JSON serializable.
print serializer.validated_data['animal']
```

If we include this one it works fine because this it just a normal field the same true to the other field except the animal which is a relational field:

```
 print serializer.validated_data['performer']
```

Now when i do this the object was saved directly to the database.

```
serializer.save()
```

But django would prompt me the **SAME TYPE ERROR!**

When removing the entire `create(self, request)` the method flow works well without an error but i would like to perform many queries inside the `create(self, request)`!. This won't do right either please help!

Comment: You need to write a serializer for `Animal` class and add it to `HeatSerializer `.

Comment: i did `animal = AnimalSerializer` in the `HeatSerializer` still wont work

Comment: Like that? `animal = AnimalSerializer(source='animal_set', many=True, read_only=True)`

Comment: i did but the animal in django-rest-framework disappear and the django views prompt me a `KeyError: 'animal'`

Comment: Which DRF version?

Comment: i got this installed djangorestframework==3.5.2

Comment: Try having `fields = '__all__'` on both serializers.

Comment: i did again but animal field still hidden, hopefully drf will consider this situation

Comment: There's a typo in my code, sorry. You have `related_name` defined, so it should be `animal = AnimalSerializer(source='heats', many=True, read_only=True)`

Comment: tsk it won't work regardless of the code

Comment: Then you have something else going on there. The code is fine and works on my end in many places.

Comment: Yes you are right since i need the pk of that animal object. I just changed it to `animal = serializers.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=None) ` and in order to get it as an object i just perform the Animal.objects.get(pk=pk), now its working. thanks a lot for giving insight

Comment: No worries. Mate.

Answer (score 0):

When you serialize on Queryset the JSON result will be into a .data object

```
animal = AnimalSerializer(your_model.animal_set(), many=True, read_only=True)
return Response(animal.data)
```